# How to use NLP to detect sentences in a long text?

Tags: nlp

I am using automatic speech recognition to extract text from an audio file. However, the output is just a long sequence of words with no punctuation whatsoever. What I'd like to do is use some NLP technique to estimate beginnings and endings of sentences, or, in other words, predict positions of punctuation markers. I found that CoreNLP can do sentence splitting, but apparently only if punctuation is already present.

Answer (score 1):

You may find relevant info in the answers to this other question: [Sentence annotation in text without punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807333/sentence-annotation-in-text-without-punctuation).

In particular, one of the answers claims the [deepsegment](https://github.com/notAI-tech/deepsegment) package works well on unpunctuated text.

Answer (score 0):

In spoken language you often find that people don't use sentences, but that the clauses simply run into each other. The degree to which this happens depends on the formality and setting -- a speech will conform more to written sentence structures than a conversation in a pub among friends.

One approach you could try is to identify words that typically begin/end sentences in written text, and see if that can help you segmenting your data. Or look for verbs, and then try to find boundaries between them; this might be clause boundaries rather than sentence boundaries, but as I said, in spoken language there often are no sentences.

Comment: I see the problem of spoken text not having clearly separated sentences. However, there must be a way to at least estimate sentence start and end points. Google Cloud's [Speech-to-Text API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) apparently does so. In addition to your suggestion it might be promising to identify patterns with regard to actual parts of speech. What I'm looking for is some libraries that already implements such functionality. Does anyone know of something relevant?

Comment: Hello, did you get anywhere with this?